# How to get android running widgets?

Tags: android

I am getting installed widgets but I need to find out only running widgets of home screen. Is there any possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I am getting installed widgets` how? And why you think that you should be able to get the widgets that user is using?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own home screen implementation, where you allow the user to add app widgets to that home screen. Then, you will know what the "running" app widgets are.

Other home screen implementations do not have to publish this information to third parties, and hopefully they do not, for privacy and security reasons.